# Sendmail submit.mc for local mail submission

Tags: linux, redhat, sendmail

I'm having an issue with Sendmail (I have 8.14.7 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7) in that mail submitted locally by scripts on the server is having the domain name changed. I have domain1.com domain2.com and domain3.com. When mail is submitted by local script for user@domain2.com, it is being changed to user@domain1.com. Everything else is working fine. Incoming mail from the Internet to user@domain2.com goes to user@domain2.com. I am using virtusertable definitions that are working fine. I had read that submit.mc is what guides local mail submission like this instead of sendmail.mc. Can anyone look at my submit.mc below and see if I have an error or am missing something?

```
divert(-1)
#
# Copyright (c) 2001-2003 Sendmail, Inc. and its suppliers.
#       All rights reserved.
#
# By using this file, you agree to the terms and conditions set
# forth in the LICENSE file which can be found at the top level of
# the sendmail distribution.
#
#

#
#  This is the prototype file for a set-group-ID sm-msp sendmail that
#  acts as a initial mail submission program.
#

divert(0)dnl
sinclude(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`linux setup')dnl
define(`confCF_VERSION', `Submit')dnl
define(`__OSTYPE__',`')dnl dirty hack to keep proto.m4 from complaining
define(`_USE_DECNET_SYNTAX_', `1')dnl support DECnet
define(`confTIME_ZONE', `USE_TZ')dnl
define(`confDONT_INIT_GROUPS', `True')dnl
dnl # If you're operating in a DSCP/RFC-4594 environment with QoS
dnl define(`confINET_QOS', `AF11')dnl
define(`confPID_FILE', `/run/sm-client.pid')dnl
dnl define(`confDIRECT_SUBMISSION_MODIFIERS',`C')dnl
FEATURE(`use_ct_file')dnl
dnl
dnl If you use IPv6 only, change [127.0.0.1] to [IPv6:::1]
FEATURE(`msp', `[127.0.0.1]')dnl
```

I'm now adding an example of the maillog for this error too below:

```
Oct 22 10:25:59 domain1 sendmail[3126]: x9MHPxwE003126: from=joe, size=220, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201910221725.x9MHPxwE003126@domain1.com>, relay=joe@localhost
Oct 22 10:25:59 domain1 sendmail[3129]: x9MHPx3O003129: from=<joe@domain1.com>, size=457, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201910221725.x9MHPxwE003126@domain1.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Oct 22 10:25:59 domain1 sendmail[3126]: x9MHPxwE003126: to=admin@domain2.com, ctladdr=joe (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30220, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (x9MHPx3O003129 Message accepted for delivery)
Oct 22 10:26:00 domain1 sendmail[3130]: x9MHPx3O003129: to=<admin@domain1.com>, ctladdr=<joe@domain1.com> (1003/1003), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30659, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Comment: Do you mean OS user `user` assigned (by virtusertable) to `domain2.com`?

Comment: user@domain2.com is assigned to a local mailbox in virtusertable like this: user@domain2.com     usermailbox

Comment: However, that's not my problem. In maillog, I see that the mail has been changed to user@domain1.com so the virtusertable entry will never get used anyway, since it is not user@domain2.com.

Comment: I'll add a maillog example to my original question above.

Answer (score 0):

`virtusertable` **only** redirects incoming email.  It rewrites envelope recipient address.

You may use `genericstable` in `sendmail.cf` to "complete" rewriting of other address (envelope sender, header sender and hader recipients).

Comment: My virtusertable is functioning properly. That's not my problem. Even in the above problem, I can still solve it using virtusertable. Local sendmail submission changes user1@domain2.com to user1@domain1.com, but if I put user1@domain1.com in my virtusertable and point it to the actual mailbox of user1@domain2.com, virtusertable redirects it to the proper local mailbox, but then on my local mail submission from scripts, any user1@domainX.com will always go to user1@domain2.com because ALL user1@domainX.com are all being changed on local submission and ONLY local submission to user1@domain1.com.

Comment: I'll add a maillog example to my original question above.